# Connect consumers to pre-configured receive endpoint

Tags: masstransit

I'm using ASPNET Core and I rely heavily on Dependency Injection.

I want my event consumers to store data from messages to the database (database is a service), but services aren't **yet** resolved when I configure consumers via:

```
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.Host("rabbitmq", "/", h =>
            {
                h.Username("root");
                h.Password("root");
            });

            configuration.ReceiveEndpoint("event-bus", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer(() => new UserCreatedConsumer(<service here>)))
            });
        });
    });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Now, what I've tried was to add consumers after service provider and container is built, using this code:

```
    var busControl = provider.GetService<IBusControl>();

    busControl.ConnectConsumer(() => new UserCreatedConsumer(
        provider.GetService<NoticeboardMasterStore>()
    ));

    busControl.ConnectConsumer(() => new TokenCreatedConsumer(
        provider.GetService<NoticeboardMasterStore>()
    ));
```

This sadly, didn't work - it just adds a weird queue called `a0062491f73f_VehiclooNoticeboardService_bus_yyboyyfcnebrfjsdbdcj8cmrbz` and the messages don't even trigger the consumer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you have a consumer with dependencies and are using a container, I'd suggest following [the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/) – particularly at the bottom where it shows how to configure consumers on a receive endpoint from the container.

In your case, this would look like:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<UserCreatedConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, configuration) =>
    {
        configuration.Host("rabbitmq", "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username("root");
            h.Password("root");
        });

        configuration.ReceiveEndpoint("event-bus", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<UserCreatedConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});

services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Any of your consumer dependences should be registered in the container as well (they can be scoped, transient, or singleton – a new scope is created for each message delivered to a consumer instance).

Comment: Yes, the dependencies are registered as services.
Thought the code you supplied me with pops: `System.ArgumentException: 'The consumer type was not found: Vehicloo.NoticeboardService.Services.Communication.Consumers.UserCreatedConsumer'` error

Comment: Just realized I had to add `x.AddConsumer` too - works now, thanks!